# Error using Nuitka for Python App that uses Numpy, Pandas and Plotly

Tags: python-3.x, windows, numpy, mingw-w64, nuitka

I've developed a PyQT5 app that also uses Numpy, Pandas and Plotly. To package it up I decided to use Nuitka however since the product is for the end users who won't be familiar with Python, I want to make sure the interpreter is packaged up along with the app as a single binary (similar to PyInstaller).

I'm running the following command however have been getting errors that I'm struggling to figure out how to fix:

```
$ python -m nuitka --standalone --show-progress --recurse-all --plugin-enable=numpy main.py
```

I'm using PyCharm and all the libraries are in the Virtual Environment in project directory. The version of Python I'm using is 3.9.

An executable binary is generated in Windows however upon running I receive the following error message:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PlotlyExample\main.dist>main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module numpy.core>
  File "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module numpy.core.multiarray>
  File "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module numpy.core.overrides>
ImportError: LoadLibraryExW 'C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.pyd' failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module numpy>
  File "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module numpy.core>
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: LoadLibraryExW 'C:\Users\\user\PYCHAR~1\PLOTLY~1\MAIN~1.DIS\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.pyd' failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**Sample Code:**
https://pastebin.com/RjRYUk0C

Any ideas? Thanks!